# Web scraping - how to identify main content on a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, html

Given a news article webpage (from any major news source such as times or bloomberg), I want to  identify the main article content on that page and throw out the other misc elements such as ads, menus, sidebars, user comments.

What's a generic way of doing this that will work on most major news sites?

What are some good tools or libraries for data mining? (preferably python based)

Comment: see how `Readability` bookmark is implemented http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/

Comment: A browser that does this would be a huge threat to online ads.

Comment: the code to the original bookmarklet is here: http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/source/browse/  `Readability` is now a service and it's code is not available.

Comment: I think this is a really good case for ML usage. The ML model can be trained by libraries like `readability` and also human supervision.

Comment: There are many libraries that try to do this for you (which are not obviously 100 accurate). Check this out  https://github.com/nabinkhadka/readable-content

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no way to do this that's guaranteed to work, but one strategy you might use is to try to find the element with the most visible text inside of it.

Comment: Actually there are too many websites with too much garbage inside them. So the algorithm should try to make sense of the element contents and find its position cause in many websites the main content resides at the center of the page. I think the optimum solution is to use ML and train it with these libraries and human supervision.

Answer (score 34):

There are a number of ways to do it, but, none will always work.  Here are the two easiest:

- if it's a known finite set of websites: in your scraper convert each url from the normal url to the print url for a given site (cannot really be generalized across sites)
- Use the arc90 readability algorithm (reference implementation  is in javascript) http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/ .  The short version of this algorithm is it looks for divs with p tags within them.  It will not work for some websites but is generally pretty good.

Comment: +1 for Readability. Since Readability works best for article pages as opposed to homepages it would work best when an RSS feed is parsed for article URLs.

Comment: I should've added links to the python ports of the readability algorithm: http://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=python&q=readability&repo=&langOverride=&x=22&y=9&start_value=1

Comment: I wonder why I didn't discover this before. It was superb, compared to the previous ad-hocs methods which I developed myself.

Answer (score 14):

A while ago I wrote a [simple Python script](https://github.com/chrisspen/webarticle2text) for just this task. It uses a heuristic to group text blocks together based on their depth in the DOM. The group with the most text is then assumed to be the main content. It's not perfect, but works generally well for news sites, where the article is generally the biggest grouping of text, even if broken up into multiple div/p tags.

You'd use the script like: `python webarticle2text.py <url>`

Answer (score 13):

Check the following script. It is really amazing:

```
from newspaper import Article
URL = "https://www.ksat.com/money/philippines-stops-sending-workers-to-qatar"
article = Article(URL)
article.download()
print(article.html)
article.parse()
print(article.authors)
print(article.publish_date)
#print(article.text)
print(article.top_image)
print(article.movies)
article.nlp()
print(article.keywords)
print(article.summary)
```

More documentation can be found at http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper you should install it using:

```
pip3 install newspaper3k
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer since this points to the best library for the job asked by OP.

Answer (score 9):

Diffbot offers a free(10.000 urls) API to do that, don't know if that approach is what you are looking for, but it might help someone http://www.diffbot.com/

Comment: Nice, i've been thinking for a while about building something like that myself =)

Answer (score 8):

For a solution in Java have a look at https://github.com/kohlschutter/boilerpipe :

> The boilerpipe library provides algorithms to detect and remove the surplus "clutter" (boilerplate, templates) around the main textual content of a web page.
>
> The library already provides specific strategies for common tasks (for example: news article extraction) and may also be easily extended for individual problem settings.

But there is also a python wrapper around this available here:

https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe

Answer (score 8):

There is a recent (early 2020) comparison of various methods of extracting article body, without and ads, menus, sidebars, user comments, etc. - see https://github.com/scrapinghub/article-extraction-benchmark. A [report](https://github.com/scrapinghub/article-extraction-benchmark/releases/download/v1.0.0/paper-v1.0.0.pdf), data and evaluation scripts are available. It compares many options mentioned in the answers here, as well as some options which were not mentioned:

- [python-readability](https://github.com/buriy/python-readability)
- [boilerpipe](https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe)
- [newspaper3k](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper)
- [dragnet](https://github.com/dragnet-org/dragnet)
- [html-text](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text)
- [Diffbot](https://www.diffbot.com/products/automatic/)
- Scrapinghub [AutoExtract](https://scrapinghub.com/data-api-news/)

In short, "smart" open source libraries are adequate if you need to remove e.g. sidebar and menu, but they don't handle removal of unnecessary content inside articles, and are quite noisy overall; sometimes they remove an article itself and return nothing. Commercial services use Computer Vision and Machine Learning, which allows them to provide a much more precise output.

For some use cases simpler libraries like [html-text](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text) are preferrable, both to commercial services and to "smart" open source libraries - they are fast, and ensure information is not missing (i.e. recall is high).

I would not recommend copy-pasting code snippets, as there are many edge cases even for a seemingly simple task of extracting text from HTML, and there are libraries available (like [html-text](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text) or html2text) which should be handling these edge cases.

To use a commercial tool, in general one needs to get an API key, and then use a client library. For example, for AutoExtract by Scrapinghub (disclaimer: I work there) you would need to install `pip install scrapinghub-autoextract`. There is a Python API available - see https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapinghub-autoextract README for details, but an easy way to get extractions is to create a .txt file with URLs to extract, and then run

```
python -m autoextract urls.txt --page-type article --api-key <API_KEY> --output res.jl
```

Comment: Nice recap. I'd also add https://www.html-reader.com/en/ to the bunch (disclaimer: I haven't tried it but it looks all right for my simple use case)

Answer (score 6):

It might be more useful to extract the RSS feeds (`<link type="application/rss+xml" href="..."/>`) on that page and parse the data in the feed to get the main content.

Comment: NB: for ATOM feeds `type="application/atom+xml"`

Comment: A good idea, but this can be hit or miss, since a lot of feeds only include an article summary. Which is understandable, since the point of most news sites is to get you to view ads, which you generally won't inside an RSS reader.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility of separating "real" content from noise is by [measuring HTML density](http://ai-depot.com/articles/the-easy-way-to-extract-useful-text-from-arbitrary-html/) of the parts of a HTML page.

You will need a bit of experimentation with the thresholds to extract the "real" content, and I guess you could improve the algorithm by applying heuristics to specify the exact bounds of the HTML segment after having identified the interesting content.

Update: Just found out the URL above does not work right now; [here is an alternative link](http://web.archive.org/web/20080620121103/http://ai-depot.com/articles/the-easy-way-to-extract-useful-text-from-arbitrary-html/) to a cached version of archive.org.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to scrape it from the web page - too many things could mess it up - but instead see which web sites publish RSS feeds. For example, the Guardian's RSS feed has most of the text from their leading articles:

http://feeds.guardian.co.uk/theguardian/rss

I don't know if The Times (The London Times, not NY) has one because it's behind a paywall. Good luck with that...

Comment: Most of the RSS feeds I've seen only have short abstracts of the full articles.